# Printing in parallel processes using Python sub-process module

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am using python subprocesses as follows.

```
import subprocess


p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test1.py'])
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test2.py'])

p1.wait()
p2.wait()

print('The main and sub-processes are finished')
```

There is a print statement in both test1.py and test2.py. Its desired behavior is to print 'test1' or 'test2' continuously.

I was expecting a mingled kind of output as they are running in parallel. However, I am just seeing only 'test1':

```
test1
test1
test1
and so on.
```

What am I missing here?

Desired output: Both print statements should be on STDOUT.

NOTE: This a very simplified example of the problem. 
NOTE: Imagine the test1 and test2 looks like this.

test1.py:

```
for i in range(100000):
    print('test1')
```

test2.py:

```
for i in range(100000):
    print('test2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works fine. You just get a lot of trailing output from one of the processes as the busy loops do not run in tandem. Try changing your test1 and test2 to this:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(1000):
    print('test2')
    sleep(0.1)
```

And you will see your expected output.

Comment: It worked. However, Ideally, I wouldn't wanna use a sleep. Could there be another work-around?

Comment: This was just for demonstration.  What it proves is that your output is handled in parallel and it is interleaved - based on how the subprocesses get executed.  If you need to synchronise them, then you need for example locks. There is no guarantee on any platform that threads get exactly the same amount of CPU/IO time.

Comment: If you loop a million times and print out something, due to uneven execution of threads one of them will have about 10000 iterations left when the first one finishes, making the tail always look "bad". Try running your script and redirecting output to a file and inspect the file. You can see that the bulk of the files shows interleaved "test1" and "test2", and there are single outputs only in the beginning (test2 not started yet) and at the end as explained above.

Comment: When I ran your code, the first time I had many trailing test1 messages, but the second attempt the messages were test2. Which means we just do not know which one of your threads complete first.